# I have an issue with swiper and arrow buttons (magic)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, swiper.js

Arrows of swiper not showed before swipe or change any property in css(not inline)

link of demo: http://sinneren.ru/side/giftormagic/views/index0.html

How to: To see my bug You must use browser in mobile orientation (Chrome, Safary, may be any else). Scroll to big white block with roses. Do you see arrows? Nope, and if you swipe once on it, or You change any property in css, or You change focus on block - they will be shown. It's magic. And it's shown before, but placed under white block. I change any styles, positions, used hacks with init-callback and timers to change inline styles - it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this only happens in Chrome (right?) it could be anti aliasing issue. Try this property: 
`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` on button style. If that doesn't help try:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); 
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: It happens on Chrome desktop and Safari on iPad(7.0.x) & iPhone 5(i don't know iOS version). With this property on Chrome it works but not in Safari mobiles

Comment: Real magic :) ... i would also tried to add this:  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); (no good explanation...)